# Separating a numerical or alphanumerical data from a string

Tags: r, regex

I want to separate a data of the form: " Score Card 45" into the form "score card"  "45" i.e . I want to separate on the basis of type of data.

Can anyone please help me with it?

Another eg. : "Data type  45tr43"    into       "Data type"   "45tr43"

Comment: Could you provide more example rows? Looks like standard space separated text file that could be imported as `read.table("myFile.txt", sep = " ")`

Answer (score 2):

You might find it satisfactory to just use `strsplit` here, for a base R option:

```
input <- "Data type 45tr43"
parts <- strsplit(input, "(?<=\\D) (?=\\d)", perl=TRUE)
parts

[1] "Data type" "45tr43"
```

This assumes a splitting logic of a split on a space character which borders on the left with a non-digit, and on the right with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexpr` to find the first `numeric` and split the string at this position using `substr`. To remove spaces at the begin or end you can use `trimws` and in case you want only lower case in the output use `tolower`.

```
x  <- " Score Card 45"
i <- regexpr("\\d", x)
trimws(c(substr(x, 1, i-1), substring(x, i)))
#[1] "Score Card" "45"
trimws(substring(x, c(1,i), c(i-1,nchar(x))))
#[1] "Score Card" "45"
tolower(trimws(c(substr(x, 1, i-1), substring(x, i))))
#[1] "score card" "45"

x  <- "Data type 45tr43"
i <- regexpr("\\d", x)
trimws(c(substr(x, 1, i-1), substring(x, i)))
#[1] "Data type" "45tr43"
```